# Python 3.3.6 re.compsre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to compile below regex in interactive mode (python 3.3.6) but I get the following error:

```
>>> NAME = r'(?P<NAME>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)'
>>> NUM = r'(?P<NUM>\d+)'
>>> PLUS = r'(?P<PLUS>+)'
>>> TIMES = r'(?P<TIMES>\*)'
>>> EQ = r'(?P<EQ>=)'
>>> WS = r'(?P<WS>\s+)'
>>>
>>> master_pat = re.compile('|'.join([NAME, NUM, PLUS, TIMES, EQ, WS]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 214, in compile
   return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/re.py", line 283, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/sre_compile.py", line 491, in compile
p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 747, in parse
p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 359, in _parse_sub
itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 695, in _parse
p = _parse_sub(source, state)
  File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 359, in _parse_sub
itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/Users/henry/.virtualenvs/python_cookbook/lib/python3.3/sre_parse.py", line 568, in _parse
raise error("nothing to repeat")
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Close voters: "Nothing to repeat" is a moderately cryptic yet easy to get error message from deep within a regex.   Why arguably caused by a typo, this question has value to hang around and provide the answer to others who typo the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PLUS = r'(?P<PLUS>+)'
```

The `+` here is a quantifier, so escape it like you did with `*`:

```
PLUS = r'(?P<PLUS>\+)'
```